# Baby Rudin 2.12 vs power set of N

Tags: first-countable

Baby Rudin 2.12 states that union of countable number of countable sets is countable. Doesn’t this contradict that the power set of $N$ is uncountable? Can somebody please explain?

What I mean is: set of 2-element subsets is countable, set of 3-element subsets is countable etc. There’s a countable number of these collections, so why isn’t their union countable?

Comment: Hi, please explain your argument that the power set of the natural numbers is countable, so that we can point out the flaw.

Comment: The power set of $\Bbb{N}$ is not the union of a countable number of countable sets. Read about [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). A countable collection of a countable sets can be enumerated using a [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

Comment: Exactly, @RobArthan!  Thanks!.

Comment: What I mean is: set of 2-element subsets is countable, set of 3-element subsets is countable etc. There’s a countable number of these collections, so why isn’t their union countable?

Comment: But what about the infinite subsets of the natural numbers ?

Comment: I see what you mean. So if we only take finite sets, then it’s countable?

Comment: Yes, by your nice argument.

Answer (score 0):

The set of prime number is countable denote it by $\{p_1,...,p_i\}$
Let $A_n$ a family of countable sets $f_i:A_i\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ an injection, write $g(a_i)=p_i^{f_i(a_i)}, a_i\in A_i$; $g$ is injective.

If $S$ is a set $|S|<P(S)|$ the canonical trick, let $f:S\rightarrow P(S)$ bijection; $T\subset S, T=\{s\in S, s$ is not an element of $f(s)\}$, suppose that $f(t)=T, t\in T$ impossible by definition of $T$, but if $t$ is not in $T$, it is in $T$ by definition, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what one thing has to do with the other.  The power set of $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.  The union of $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is countable, however.  In fact, it's $\mathbb{N}$.  The cardinality is the number of elements in the set.  The union is the set of elements in any one of the sets in the collection.  Two different things.

Comment: Please see my added details above.

Comment: @user623949 You are correct in that there are countably many finite subsets, but  what about the infinite subsets?  There are uncountably many of those.